# Using advanced IF in Formula field

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field, business-logic

I am trying to get the percentage of process completion. I have some checkboxes, and I want to check if each one is checked or not. For every checked box, I will increase some value and then get the percentage.

Checkboxes:

- isEmailed__c
- isSubmitted__c
- isCalled__c

Long Percentage field:
Percentage__c

**The logic:**

```
Long count 0;
If(isEmailed__c)
  count++;
If(isSybmitted__c)
  count++;
If(isCalled__c)
  count++;

percentage__c = (count/3)*100;
```

How could I implement this logic using a formula field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this

```
((IF(isEmailed = True, 1,0)
+
IF(isSubmitted = True, 1,0)
+
IF(isCalled = True, 1,0))
/3) * 100
```

The if you add any more checkboxes that need to be worked in, you just need to add another

```
IF(Checkbox_Field__c = True, 1,0)
```

and also increase the number you are dividing by

Comment: Worked just well after removing (* 100), Thanks @chris-duncombe . I will mark your answer as the right answer in a minute ;)

Comment: Hmmmm. it shoudl work with the *100.  without it, you just have a decimal.  I mean the decimal is fine, just figured you would want a whole number between 0 and 100.  Did it give an error?

Comment: Maybe because I set the field type to "Percent", it's automatically multiplied to 100 @chris-duncombe

Comment: oh yes, that's it.  I should have thought of just setting it to percent in the first place.  I wrote the rule as if it would be a number formula, so I would have to multiply by 100.  Setting it up as a percentage is much better.

Comment: Really only need `IF(Checkbox_Field__c, 1, 0)`.  Checking if a boolean field is equal to True is redundant.

Comment: @ScottW, I agree with you, that is true, but I generally only do that in Apex code.  When using formula fields, often admins might be looking at and updating the formulas, so I try to make it as clear and readable as possible.  Although using = true is redundant, it does make it more readable and much more clear to someone who might not be familiar with syntax.

Comment: ("The if" -> "Then if"?)

Comment: @Peter, is that a question?  If so, I don't understand.